# Tent map and quadratic maps

Tags: dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

Consider the tent map defined on $[0, 1]$:
$$f(x) = 2x, \; 0<x<\frac{1}{2} \;\; and \;\; f(x) = 2(1-x), \; \frac{1}{2} \leq x \leq 1.$$

I showed that $f$ is topological conjugate with $F(x) = 4x(1-x)$.

Are there other quadratic functions $F_\alpha(x) = \alpha x(1-x)$ for which $f$ is topological conjugate?.

Can someone give me a hint?

Thank you!

Comment: Hint: presumably $f$ is onto, although you mention no domain...

Comment: $f$ and $F_\alpha$ are both onto. I don't understand how to conclude if they are topologically conjugate or not (when $\alpha \neq 4$). Can you give me more details? Thank you!

Comment: If if you have two topologically conjugate maps, both are onto or both are not onto. Do you see why? Just look at the conjugacy. That's why $\alpha=4$ is special (for your question).